# Source Generator Causing TypeLoadException During Startup

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, sourcegenerators

I'm working on a .NET 7 project where I'm parsing log files using regex. I have several classes with a regex expression that try to parse a line of text and if successful return an instance of the class with its properties populated. It's getting tedious to create a new class, all of the properties, and a static parse function that is basically boilerplate at the point. So, I'm trying to create a Source Generator that finds classes with an attribute with the regex for the class to use. I've gotten to the point where I'm generating a valid file that satisfies my requirements and compiles.

But when I try to run the program, I'm getting a `System.TypeLoadException` exception.

I've tried cleaning the solution and deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, but I still get the same exception during startup. If I copy the output of the source generator into the project and not trigger the source generator, then it works fine, it gets to my main function and uses the generated parser without any issues. I was even able to use IL-Spy to decompile the .dll, recompile from the command line, and run it successfully.

Here's the Debug Output from VS 2022:

```
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\_______\source\repos\ScheduleLogParser\ScheduleLogParser\bin\Debug\net7.0\ScheduleLogParser.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\hotreload\Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.IO.Pipes.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Linq.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Collections.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Console.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Threading.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Security.AccessControl.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Security.Claims.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Runtime.Loader.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Failure has occurred while loading a type.

'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. 
'ScheduleLogParser.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.4\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
The program '[39096] ScheduleLogParser.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here's source generator .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      <LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
      <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here's the consumer .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ScheduleLogParser.ParserGenerator.Attributes\ScheduleLogParser.ParserGenerator.Attributes.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ScheduleLogParser.ParserGenerator\ScheduleLogParser.ParserGenerator.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here's the `ISourceGenerator`:

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace ScheduleLogParser.ParserGenerator;

[Generator]
public sealed class SourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        // Register a syntax receiver that will be created for each generation pass
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new SyntaxReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        // retrieve the populated receiver 
        if (context.SyntaxContextReceiver is not SyntaxReceiver receiver)
            return;

        foreach (var workItem in receiver.WorkItems)
        {
            context.AddSource($"{workItem.ParserClass.FullName()}.g.cs", ClassGenerator.GenerateClass(workItem));
        }
        
        //Write the log entries
        context.AddSource("Logs", SourceText.From($"/*\nGenerated: {DateTime.Now}\n{string.Join("\n", receiver.Log)}\n*/", Encoding.UTF8));
    }
}
```

Here's the source class:

```cs
namespace ScheduleLogParser.Parsers;

/* language=regex */
[ParserGenerator(@"^(?<TimeOnly_TimeStamp>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s+Checking stocked material constraint for operation (?<int_OprSeq>\d+) material (?<string_MtlPartNum>.+?) for (?<DateOnly_CheckingDate>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})\. --- (?<string_Method>\w+)$")]
public sealed partial class CheckingStockedMaterial : ILogLineParser<CheckingStockedMaterial>
{
}
```

Here's the generated file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ScheduleLogParser.Parsers;

public sealed partial class CheckingStockedMaterial : ScheduleLogParser.Parsers.ILogLineParser<ScheduleLogParser.Parsers.CheckingStockedMaterial>, ScheduleLogParser.Parsers.ILogLineParser
{
    private static readonly Regex _regex = new(@"^(?<TimeOnly_TimeStamp>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s+Checking stocked material constraint for operation (?<int_OprSeq>\d+) material (?<string_MtlPartNum>.+?) for (?<DateOnly_CheckingDate>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})\. --- (?<string_Method>\w+)$");

    public int LineNumber { get; private init; }

    public TimeOnly TimeStamp { get; private init; }

    public int OprSeq { get; private init; }

    public string MtlPartNum { get; private init; }

    public DateOnly CheckingDate { get; private init; }

    public string Method { get; private init; }

    public static CheckingStockedMaterial? Parse(string line, int lineNumber)
    {
        var match = _regex.Match(line);
        return match.Success == true ?
            new CheckingStockedMaterial
            {
                LineNumber = lineNumber,
                TimeStamp = TimeOnly.Parse(match.Groups["TimeOnly_TimeStamp"].ValueSpan),
                OprSeq = int.Parse(match.Groups["int_OprSeq"].ValueSpan),
                MtlPartNum = match.Groups["string_MtlPartNum"].Value,
                CheckingDate = DateOnly.Parse(match.Groups["DateOnly_CheckingDate"].ValueSpan),
                Method = match.Groups["string_Method"].Value
            } : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Output generated files with
   `<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>`. Inspect files, you can copy them into your solution and run console app without generator.
2. If you plan to use generator on projects from .net7 and onwards, try to switch to minimal version required.
   `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` v4.4.0 in this case.
3. Use `IIncrementalGenerator` for generator
4. Use `ForAttributeWithMetadataName` for searching the attribute within your source code.